# ERROR: Insufficient page size to print frequency table in SAS PROC FREQ

Tags: sas

Could anybody tell me why does the compiler gives me an error - `"ERROR: Insufficient page size to print frequency table."` while running proc freq in sas.

I am trying to run a very simple peice of code.

```
proc freq data = seaepi; 
   tables trt* sex/ out = temp; 
run;
```

I really appreciate your effort involved.

Thanks in advance.

*> crossposted from SAS-L*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had this problem before.  This literally means that you have too many columns or you columns are too wide to fit on the page and so it will not print.  Try to reduce the font size or reduce the number columns to see if you still have the problem.

Sometimes the way you handle a problem like this depends on your output destination.  It would be helpful to know if you are using ODS PDF, or HTML or are just writing to the output window.

Answer (score 2):

Run it with

```
option pagesize=max;
```

and see what that looks like. As mentioned already, the result will depend on what kind of output you are using. At least you can look at this output and see what it needs for a page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not tried, have a look at the options statement in SAS [SAS Options Statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/61724/HTML/default/a000309878.htm). There is a PageSize option which can be set.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since you've already requested that the frequency table is written to an output dataset, you could disable printing it in the results tab:

```
proc freq data = seaepi noprint; 
   tables trt* sex/ out = temp; 
run;
```

If necessary, you could then export your output dataset or chop it into smaller bits for viewing via proc print.